# is there a simple way of obtaining the RGB of the brush used to erase the window background?

Tags: winapi, gdi

I'm looking for a simpler way (if there is one) of finding out what RGB is used by the brush that Windows uses to erase a window background.

The problem I'm trying to solve in the most elegant way is as follows:

When registering the class, I specify a brush this way:

```
      hbrBackground   := GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_WINDOW);
```

when processing the WM_PAINT, I'm using ExtTextOut specifying ETO_OPAQUE and the rectangle (so it clears it.)

Currently, I am using:

```
    SetBkColor(dc, GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOW));
```

That has an obvious downside, if the brush used when registering the class changes then, the programmer has to remember or be aware that the same change must be made in the SetBkColor instruction found in WM_PAINT.  That's not good.

One way of solving the problem is to use GetClassLongPtr to get the background brush then, use GetObject on the brush to get its LOGBRUSH which contains the brush's RGB which can be passed to SetBkColor.

My question is: is using GetClassLongPtr followed by GetObject the simplest way of getting the RGB value I need to pass to SetBkColor ?  I'm hoping there is a simpler (more straightforward) way than that.

Thank you very much for your help.

PS: I'm looking for a straight API solution in C/C++ or Delphi.  No .net or any other framework solution.

Comment: Just connect the two with a shared constant. `const int BACKGROUND_COLOR = COLOR_WINDOW;` and then you can say `GetSysColorBrush(BACKGROUND_COLOR)` and `GetSysColor(BACKGROUND_COLOR)`. Note that for the case of a class registration, you typically say `windowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(1 + BACKGROUNDCOLOR);`

Comment: Thank you Raymond.  Though not very likely, that solution still leaves open the possibility for the colors used for the background and the text to end up out of synch (e.g, the programmer directly changes the brush used to register the class to something other than "BACKGROUND_COLOR".)  I want to eliminate that possibility.

Comment: @ScienceAmateur In fact, if, according to you, the programmer changes the brush used to register the class, then your method will also change the background brush obtained through `GetClassLongPtr`, because `GetClassLongPtr` retrieves the specified value from the `WNDCLASSEX` structure associated with the specified window.

Comment: @ Strive, that is what I want.  By using GetClassLongPtr and GetObject, I can ensure that the background color used for the text and the window are always in synch.  I just wonder if there is a simpler way than having to use GetClassLongPtr followed by GetObject.

Comment: If you don't trust the next developer to keep the two in sync, then what are you going to do if they change the brush to something that's not a solid color brush? At any rate, you can call `GetObject` to get a `LOGBRUSH` that describes the brush, and then decode the results to see what color is in it. Hopefully, it'll be a `BS_SOLID` and you can pluck out the `lbColor`.

Comment: Your proposed solution is the only solution available. That makes it the easiest (and also the hardest) solution. It is reliable, too, as long as you understand its limitations. It won't work for brushes, that aren't `BS_SOLID`. It also won't work for window classes that register a `NULL` brush and/or handle the [`WM_ERASEBKGND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-erasebkgnd) message.

Comment: @ IInspectable, thank you.  Yes, I realize there are some limitations which I don't think are completely avoidable (in the case of a NULL brush, choose some other color but, if the brush isn't solid, that leads to an ambiguous situation.)

Comment: @ Raymond, it's not so much that I don't trust the programmer. It's simply that it seems a bit too much to expect for a programmer to be aware of each and everyone of these subtle dependencies in the code.  When faced with thousands (if not tens of thousands) of lines of code spread in a number of modules, realizing there is a dependency between the brush used to register  the class and the color of the text when handling WM_PAINT is something cannot be expected.

Comment: I thought the `BACKGROUND_COLOR` constant was a clear enough indicator that "If you want to change the background color, change this constant." To make it even more explicit,  you can factor it further: Helper class `WindowBackground` with methods `GetBrush()` and `GetColor()` - if somebody sees `wc.hbrBackground = WindowBackground::GetBrush()` and they want to change the background brush, they would know that the way to do that is to go change the `WindowBackground::GetBrush()` method, and then they'll see that it's connected to `WindowBackground::GetColor()`.